# Why do I get an Undefined reference error when trying to compile?

Tags: c++, oop, undefined

Just had a little problem that I haven't been able to figure out yet.
I was using a similar program structure for a different project, but the problem boils down to this. I have two cpp files, which are:

Trading_dte.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Dte
{
    public:
    int addition(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
};
```

dummy.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Trading_dte.hpp"

Dte obj;

int check()
{
    std::cout<<obj.addition(6,9);
}
```

I created a header file called Trading_dte.hpp :

```
# pragma once
#include <iostream>

class Dte
{
    public:
    int addition(int a, int b);
};
```

Now when I try compiling using the command :

```
g++ Trading_dte.cpp dummy.cpp
```

I get the error :

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccCcM8R6.o: in function `check':
dummy.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `Dte::addition(int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm sure it's something small, but I just can't figure what.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your cpp file need to be written differently

```
#include "Trading_dte.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int Dte::addition(int a, int b)
{
  return a + b;
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling to find a good SO answer/blog post/whatever explaining WHY this is the right thing to do.

Comment: @orhtej2 the class declaration is in the header, the implementation in the .cpp or alternatively you can put everything in the header.

Answer (score 3):

You've created two separate `Dte` classes, one visible to `main` and another visible only in `Trading_dte.cpp`. The one visible to `main`, defined in `Trading_dte.hpp` has a declaration of the `addition` member function but no definition.

Probably the easiest thing to do is to drop `Trading_dte.cpp` and put the implementation into the class definition in `Trading_dte.hpp`.

`Trading_dte.hpp`:

```
# pragma once

class Dte
{
    public:
    int addition(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
};
```

Note that I also removed the `#include <iostream>` line. You don't need it in the header file because you don't use it in the class.